# Changing the x-label in HTML Canvas charts

Tags: javascript, charts, html5-canvas

Hi I am using HTML Canvas charts. In one of the charts can I change the label of x-axis?

The source code for the chart is :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>


</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function () {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
            {
                animationEnabled: true,
                theme: "theme2",
                title:{
                    text: "Multi Series Spline Chart - Hide / Unhide via Legend"
                },
                axisY:[{
                    lineColor: "#4F81BC",
                    tickColor: "#4F81BC",
                    labelFontColor: "#4F81BC",
                    titleFontColor: "#4F81BC",
                    lineThickness: 2,
                },
                    {
                        lineColor: "#C0504E",
                        tickColor: "#C0504E",
                        labelFontColor: "#C0504E",
                        titleFontColor: "#C0504E",
                        lineThickness: 2,

                    }],
                data: [
                    {
                        type: "spline", //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
                        showInLegend: true,
                        dataPoints: [
                            { x: 10, y: 51 },
                            { x: 20, y: 45},
                            { x: 30, y: 50 },
                            { x: 40, y: 62 },
                            { x: 50, y: 95 },
                            { x: 60, y: 66 },
                            { x: 70, y: 24 },
                            { x: 80, y: 32 },
                            { x: 90, y: 16}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        type: "spline",
                        axisYIndex: 1,
                        showInLegend: true,
                        dataPoints: [
                            { x: 10, y: 201 },
                            { x: 20, y: 404},
                            { x: 30, y: 305 },
                            { x: 40, y: 405 },
                            { x: 50, y: 905 },
                            { x: 60, y: 508 },
                            { x: 70, y: 108 },
                            { x: 80, y: 300 },
                            { x: 90, y: 101}
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                legend: {
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    itemclick: function (e) {
                        if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                            e.dataSeries.visible = false;
                        } else {
                            e.dataSeries.visible = true;
                        }
                        chart.render();
                    }
                }
            });

        chart.render();
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Now here we can see that x-values is 10,20,30... My question is can we change them to other format like 10am or 10pm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a **suffix** (or a **prefix**) to the x-axis with `chart.options.axisX`

```
chart.options.axisX = { suffix: "AM" };
```

Or you can add both like this:

```
chart.options.axisX = { prefix: "/", suffix: "AM" };
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Also if you can tell me that how can I change the whole x-axis to the hour format displaying from 12am to 11 pm. That would be great.

Comment: If the suffix solution work, please accept the answer, and post a different question with the specification of the am/pm (in that way anyone can help you, not only me). Of course I will try to help you.